# Express that something is trendy with 流行

Tags: nuances, wago-and-kango

Do these three sentences are right to express that something is trendy? What is the difference in meaning or nuances?

> 青色が流行になっている
>
> 青色が流行りになっている
>
> 青色が流行っている

Answer (score 2, accepted):

流行る【はやる】 and 流行する【りゅうこうする】 are a [wago-kango pair](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wago-and-kango). They are interchangeable in the context of fashion trends except that the latter is a little stiffer. Both are used also in contexts of infectious diseases (e.g., インフルエンザが流行る/流行する), but 流行する is preferred in serious academic contexts.

流行る also means "(for a restaurant, etc) to be popoular". この店は流行っている simply sounds to me like the restaurant is popular, but この店は流行している sounds like the popularity is a temporary trend.

流行になっている and 流行している are almost the same, but the former expresses a (recent) change in trends, whereas the latter expresses only the current situation. The same is true regarding the difference between 流行りになっている and 流行っている, but I feel 流行りになっている is a bit uncommon.